# Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.equinox.preferences"

Tags: java, eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler

I have set up the Git remote repository on a local machine for a Java project, basically we trying to work on same project from two different places, dedicated GIT server is in other end.

> Steps which I went through!

•   Update host file to add the new server

```
Go to "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" and add the following line at the end:
# Git server
123.123.12.123  wrkGitServer
```

Which I have done successfully;

•   Then configure eclipse to use Git and import the project (successfully imported the project from remote to local which is a simple Java class file to run;

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

    }

}
```

I get an error

**Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld**

When I looked at the built-in ErrorLog of Eclipse:

```
Window -> Show View -> General -> Error Log
```

I got;

[image]

When I double clicked on

1. "Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.equinox.preferences""

   org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
       at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4397)
       at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4312)
       at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4283)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:472)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkWidget(Widget.java:363)
       at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.getSelection(Tree.java:3427)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.getSelection(TreeViewer.java:256)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.setSelection(TreeViewer.java:344)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.setSelectionToWidget(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2521)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.setSelectionToWidget(StructuredViewer.java:1769)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.setSelectionToWidget(AbstractTreeViewer.java:2970)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1450)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.preservingSelection(TreeViewer.java:403)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.preservingSelection(StructuredViewer.java:1404)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.refresh(StructuredViewer.java:1533)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.refresh(ColumnViewer.java:555)
       at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.refresh(StructuredViewer.java:1490)
       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.classpath.RuntimeClasspathViewer$1.preferenceChange(RuntimeClasspathViewer.java:58)
       at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences$3.run(EclipsePreferences.java:896)
       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
       at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.firePreferenceEvent(EclipsePreferences.java:899)
       at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.put(EclipsePreferences.java:912)
       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.jres.JREsUpdater$1.run(JREsUpdater.java:91)
       at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
2. "Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
   user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'H:\'. If this is
   not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
   EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
   This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page. "

   An exception stack trace is not available.
3. "Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
   Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
   The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
   this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
   Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
   This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
   "

   An exception stack trace is not available.

**Question is:**

How do I resolve this problem and run the project file? please show me the directions, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem,

1. On the project folder delete `.project` and `.classpath` files
2. Copied the same files from the different project
3. Closed the Eclipse and restarted
4. Refresh **f5** the project and run!!!

   [image: Project Folder]